# How can I consume paginated resource using Monix in Scala?

Tags: scala, monix

I have a paginated resource and I want to consume it recursively with Monix. I want to have an Observable that is going to emit downloaded elements and recursively consume pages. Here is a simple example. It doesn't work of course. It emits first page, then first page + second page, then first + second + third. And I want it to emit first, then second, then third and so on.

```
object Main extends App {

  sealed trait Event
  case class Loaded(xs: Seq[String]) extends Event
  // probably should just finish stream instead of this event
  case object Done extends Event

  // here is the problem
  def consume(page: Int, size: Int):Observable[Event] = {
    Observable.fromFuture(getPaginatedResource(page, size)).concatMap{ xs =>
      if (xs.isEmpty) Observable.pure(Done)
      else Observable.concat(Observable.pure(Loaded(xs)), consume(page + 1, size + 5))
    }
  }

  def getPaginatedResource(page: Int, size: Int):Future[Seq[String]] = Future {
    if (page * size > 100) Seq.empty
    else 0 to size map (x => s"element $x")
  }

  consume(page = 0, size = 5).foreach(println)

}
```

Any ideas?

**UPD**
Sorry, it seems like it's working and I just have a bug `size + 5`. So it seems like problem is solved, but if you see that I'm doing something wrong, please, tell me.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally recommended to avoid recursion if possible whenever using `Observable`. Since, its not easy to visualize and is generally more prone to error.

One idea would be to use `scanEvalF` since it will emit items on each step.

```
sealed trait Event
object Event {
  case class Loaded(page: Int, size: Int, items: Seq[String]) extends Event
}

def getPaginatedResource(page: Int, size: Int): Task[Loaded] = Task.pure {
  if (page * size > 100) Loaded(page, size, Seq.empty)
  else Loaded(page, size, 0.to(size).map(x => s"element $x"))
}

def consume(page: Int, size: Int): Observable[Event] = {
  Observable
    .interval(0.seconds)
    .scanEvalF(getPaginatedResource(page, size)) { (xs, _) =>
      getPaginatedResource(xs.page + 1, xs.size + 5)
    } // will emit items on each step
    .takeWhileInclusive(_.items.nonEmpty) // only take until list is empty
}

consume(0, 5)
  .foreachL(println)
  .runToFuture
```